# Fast free JavaScript IDE that supports debugging, code auto-complete, customizable UI, detailed error reporting, and supported by WIndows

Tags: windows, gratis, javascript, ide, debugging

I've checked a lot of answers here for similar questions, but my requirements were different.

**Background**:

I'm a developer transitioning from traditional compiled languages to modern web-centric languages, the lion's share being JavaScript-focused (Node.js, ExpressJS, Jasmine, etc). Even though I have Visual Studio 2013, and it has most of those features, it's insufficient for my needs out of the box, and quite frankly, buggy so far. E.g., it'll occasionally redline something that actually works.

Speaking of time, I don't have much time to try out a bunch of IDEs right now let alone get comfortable with them.

**Requirements**:

-Easy/Gentle learning curve. I want to install this thing and get going, not mess around setting up a bunch of custom crap and praying I didn't screw anything up.

-Debugging with good, detailed error reporting

-Free* (for commercial use)

-Windows 10 compatible (Most stuff rated for 8/8.1 seems to work so far)

-Offline version (No 100% cloud apps)

**Preferences**:

-Customizable UI color schemes for text/background

**Stuff I tried that I didn't like, or stuff I'm not down for since it isn't free:**

-WebStorm: Not Free. I hear great things about this IDE, here.

-Brackets: Auto-formatting is out of control with this program, and instead of easily changing this within the program/UI, you have to create configuration JSON files? Are you kidding me? Yeah, this *definitely* fails the learning curve... Stupid overkill.

-Sublime Text 2: Not free, and not javascript friendly out of the box

-Notepad++: Very handy, but still just a text editor

-JavaScript IDE for Eclipse: I still don't know what the hell I have to do to run a simple JS file with this, but I've given up. I don't even care, anymore. Over it.

-Cloud9: Cloud-based IDE. Yeah, no thanks. That's too much control in the hands of my tool instead of the other way around, plus the whole being connected to their cloud requirement. I didn't think it would be an issue until I actually tried it.

-Atom: Most annoying code-completion UX I've ever seen. First I laughed, then I cried.

-Microsoft WebMatrix 3: I couldn't install this on Windows 10, because I couldn't install its pre-reqs on Windows 10. Boo.

*  If WebStorm is the difference between night and day with free IDEs, *please* stress this point. I won't consider it an acceptable answer, but I will take your recommendation seriously and grok on the free vs. premium dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

Not the fastest but one of the most reliable of the **free** Java & JavaScript IDEs is [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) - *you might even find that a lot of things are familiar as several embedded compiler tool chains use customisations of eclipse as their IDE.*

- **Free**, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform - including Windows 7/8/10, OS/X, Linux
- Written in Java
- Highly Customisable
- Good debug & testing support
- Lots of plug-ins available for things like various version control integrations, *git, svn, *
- Learning Curve is not too steep
- Massive and helpful user base
- Several predefined packages including  [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars1) and [Eclipse for PHP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/mars1), *the latter specifically includes:*

  - *JavaScript Development Tools*
  - *PHP Development Tools*
  - *Eclipse XML Editors and Tools*
  - *Eclipse Git Team Provider*
  - *Mylyn Task List*
- Support for other web languages including PHP, XML, etc.

Comment: Would you happen to know if Eclipse has changed much in the last 8-10 years? I can't say I was terribly fond of it when I gave it a whirl back then. Either way, good answer! This one's certainly a contender, but I'm sitting tight for now.

Comment: Hi @SteveBarnes . Sorry to for this silly question, but was there any particular reason for your answer's emphasis on Java and not JavaScript?

Comment: Less to type & most IDEs that cover Java also do JS + a distinct lack of Caffeine at the time may have had a Freudian influence! I'll update.

Comment: I was in the same boat last night when I first responded x.x I came back to for updates and had to do a bit of a double-take :) Thanks for taking another peak!

Comment: No problem - It is just coming up to 06:00 here.

Comment: I gave this a whirl. I have no idea what was _supposed_ to be the UX, but after downloading it and loading one of my scripts, it decided that it wouldn't let me run said script, nor did it have code completion. I'm sure these features and abilities work *somewhere*, but not out of the box. Bad UX!

Answer (score 1):

[Brackets](http://brackets.io/) does meet (almost) all of your needs.

I am happily using it for AngularJS on Windows 10. I don't code Java and am not aware if there are/aren't plugins for your version control. Check that out for yourself. I can attest to the rest, though.

What I particularly like is the live preview mode. Changes to the HTML/CSS show up immediately in the browser, without having to save files.

Try Brackets. You won't regret it. Guaranteed - or your money refunded.

Comment: I loved the live preview feature! But yeah... It is not my goldilocks :(

Comment: You mean that Brackets is not your Goldilocks? Then, keep searching, but either comment here or (better yet) edit your question to say exactly what features it is missing, so that others can help your search. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, @Mawg. This has gone from asking a question to partaking in some half-baked across a dozen text editors and IDEs. That's exactly what I was trying to avoid... Such is life, eh?

Comment: I feel your pain ;-)  But, if you don't want to try them all out yourself (and I don't blame you), then you have to give extremely detailed requirements. Personally, I would split features into "must have" & "nice to have". YMMV, for instance, you may wish to prioritize them. Most of the SE posts  that I start never get completed. The exercise of trying to clearly explain to a 3rd party forces me to concentrate so much that I end up answering my own question. Again, YMMV. Or, you could just settle for "good enough", instead of pursuing "best" ...

Comment: Btw, your statement "Brackets: Only a text editor" totally flummoxes me. Are you sure that you have tried it? (no offence intended) It has all of the standard features that I could want of an IDE. If you find something better that also supports AngularJS, then I will switch in an instant. But, until then, I don't know of a better one (for me)

Comment: You're right. That was unfair of me. I went to try out brackets after getting ~12 different plugins. It definitely enhanced the experience, but the only debugger I tried seemed pissed off at everything that didn't meet a certain code style, and I didn't see where to tone that back. Do you have debugging plugins you can recommend? Brackets is pretty much my last straw at this point... I've tried everything else, @Mawg.

Comment: The adventure continues... I got Theseus working, but perhaps too late. Tabbing is crazy! This dang editor is tabbing all over the place (3x tabs? Sure, why not! Want a single tab? TOO BAD!) and I can't easily fix this. This definitely fails the gentle learning curve, but I haven't given up. Hopefully the devs get back to me with a solution instead of a "tough crap" reply.

Comment: I am doing all of my debugging in the developer consul of Chrome and that is enough for me. I can set breakpoints, examine variables, step through code. What more does one need? I also found a FOSS PHP module which lets me log the PHP part of my AJAX to the developer console. If you find something better, then I will use it. Please, do let us know.

Comment: Yeah, @Mawg. Debugging in it isn't what I would consider a *huge* issue, but as I'm new to a lot of this stuff, and I'm not aware of what is considered a good get-up-and-go development environment. I'll look into the Chrome debugger. That sounds pretty promising. This tabbing business with Brackets though... I'll see if I can find a way to stop it. It's weird how so many settings are set in a JSON file that you have to manually make and edit for stuff typically reserved for menu options. Weird UX... or just underdeveloped, I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, if you are new ... it is generally agreed that the best way to debug s/w that is meant for the browser - is in the browser. I use Chrome, which certainly led the way, but all of them now support it. In fact FireFox now has a developer edition browser - https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/developer/.  I am afraid that I don't understand your tab problems. I only have a single tab; keep clicking around & hope to hit the correct option :-)

Comment: For reasons I can't quite grasp, the tabbing seems restricted to whatever tabbing *Brackets* thinks should be set to. So for instance, if I do a linebreak with the ENTER key, and Brackets decides to set the tab 3 tabs in, that's the *only* place it will tab to from the beginning of the line. The only way to tab less is to Shift+Tab. It's really damn annoying, and this is the only text editor I've used that tries to enforce its own tabbing style instead of making an educated guess and then letting you do your thing. It sounds minor, but if I want to code in my style, I spend a lot fixing format

Answer (score 1):

The relatively recent release of VisualStudio Code appears to meet all the criteria. I've just now downloaded it to try out.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs?start=true

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Atom](http://atom.io).

- It is very easy to learn how to use
- It is Free
- No to much support for debugging, although you should be able to find an addon or extension
- Supports Windows 10
- Customizable in terms of overall themes (called "ui themes") and code themes (called "syntax themes").  There is a vast repository of themes (see [here](https://atom.io/themes))

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't, but I almost downvoted this answer. Atom has what I would consider to be one of the dumbest UXs I've ever seen in a text editor. I'd share a video if it wasn't a hassle, but instead of auto-completing code, it appends the current line with the entire code snippet, so you get console.l[autocomplete option for 'log'] and instead of it doing console.log();, it does console.console.log(); Just awful.

Comment: You are right about the auto-completing feature of atom (or rather, the lack of).  I forgot about that when I was recommending it.